# My mother doesn't know

Tags: riddle

My mother doesn’t know, but I don’t mind,

Cause I’m a very famous first-of-a-kind!

Because of me, some seek reprieve,

Unless, of course, you don’t believe;

I made my case, don’t blame me

For the actions of that fateful eve.

No sugar cane, nor feast on table

Can kill my grief, no not able!

...

Who am I?

Comment: You're someone that needs to call their mother, apparently....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You are Adam, the First Man

My mother doesn’t know, but I don’t mind,

Cause I’m a very famous first-of-a-kind!

> Adam is first man. He has no mother.

Because of me, some seek reprieve,

> Adam blamed Eve for the fall of man business.

Unless, of course, you don’t believe;

> If you don't belive in the Bible or God you don't blame anyone for your human troubles

I made my case, don’t blame me

> He put the blame on Eve

For the actions of that fateful eve.

> Again. Eve's fault.

No sugar cane, nor feast on table

Can kill my grief, no not able!

> Cane and Able were sons of Adam (or grandsons? I don't actually know which)

Comment: Cain and Abel were sons of Adam indeed. Cain did kill Abel so that adds another layer of explanation.